# How to set default Product In Websites attribute for all new products?

Tags: attributes, default

When adding new products you have to set **Product In Websites** attribute in **Websites** tab. Is there a way to set a default website automatically? I only have one website, so I think it is an unnecessary step to check the main website checkbox for every product. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Did you try? If you only have one website you don't need - afaik - to add the product to the website. it is enough when you enable the product.</strike>

## Good way

Not so easy way? Write a module, add a layout.xml file and change the template of the `tab_websites` block in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml:261` and then copy the template and change it.

## Easy and hacked way

Change `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/action/websites.phtml`

Comment: Yes I did try, but no, I have to set website, otherwise product will not appear in shop. Maybe it is because I have many store view's for different languages?

Comment: When creating new product, there is a notice in websites tab:
`Items that you don't want to show in the catalog or search results should have status 'Disabled' in the desired store.`
By this I understand that when I disable this checkbox, product will no longer be visible in front-end, but How can I make this checkbox be checked by default?

Comment: I updated the answer