# Putting default for category and main website?

Tags: category, sql, default

When I create a product I always forget to put the category and the website?
Is it possible to put a default for the main category and a default for the main website?
I have already put a default so that the stock is on for a product with this sql :

```
insert into core_config_data values ( null, ‘default’, 0, ‘cataloginventory/item_options/is_in_stock’, 1 );
```

Is there also something for the defaults of the category and the website?
thx
gp

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/how-to-set-default-product-in-websites-attribute-for-all-new-products. It may help you

Comment: Thx, i have put checked="checked", but still the box isnt checked.